# C# MS Word Interoperability - how to stretch-fill last column in table

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` in a WinForms application written in c# to create a word document programmatically. **I need to create a table with the first two columns having a predefined fixed width and the third (last) column stretched to fill the remaining width of the useable page**  (if I do not specify any widths, by default, the table would stretch itself to fill the useable width of the page and all 3 columns would be resized equally, which is not what I need).

I can preset the size of the first two columns like this:

```
myTable.Columns[1].Width = 130;
myTable.Columns[2].Width = 70;
```

That part is straight forward and works ok. But I couldn't work out how to adjust the third column to stretch-fill the rest of the page width. Here's my last attempt which resulted in the third column extending way beyond the edge of the page:

```
myTable.Columns[3].Width = wordApp.UsableWidth - myTable.Columns[1].Width - myTable.Columns[2].Width;
```

I also tried not specifying a value for the width of the 3rd column hoping that it would take up the rest of the width of the table by default - but instead, the 3rd column was adjusted to some seemingly arbitrary value (with the content of cells on this column wrapped to fit) and the overall width of the table shrank to fit all 3 columns which was less than the useable width of the page.

I tried playing with different values for the following table attributes without success:

```
myTable.AllowAutoFit = true;
myTable.PreferredWidth = wordApp.UsableWidth;
```

If anyone could help, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I included the relevant block of code if this helps in anyway:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table myTable = wordDoc.Tables.Add(paraTitle.Range, 2, 3, ref missing, ref missing);
myTable.Borders.Enable = 1;
myTable.AllowAutoFit = true;
myTable.PreferredWidth = wordApp.UsableWidth;
//myTable.PreferredWidthType = WdPreferredWidthType.wdPreferredWidthAuto;
myTable.Columns[1].Width = 130;
myTable.Columns[2].Width = 70;
myTable.Columns[3].Width = wordApp.UsableWidth - myTable.Columns[1].Width - myTable.Columns[2].Width;
myTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].Range.Text = "Items returned by:";
myTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].Range.Bold = 1;
myTable.Rows[1].Cells[2].Range.Text = "Name";
myTable.Rows[1].Cells[2].Range.Bold = 1;
myTable.Rows[1].Cells[3].Range.Text = "(person's name and initials...)";
myTable.Rows[1].Cells[3].Range.Bold = 0;
myTable.Rows[2].Cells[2].Range.Text = "Date / Time";
myTable.Rows[2].Cells[2].Range.Bold = 1;
myTable.Rows[2].Cells[3].Range.Text = "(timestamp...)";
myTable.Rows[2].Cells[3].Range.Bold = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UsableWidth` refers to the `Window` width of the Word Application, not the document page width.

Instead use:
`doc.PageSetup.PageWidth - (doc.PageSetup.LeftMargin + doc.PageSetup.RightMargin);`